# Avoid running a code if already executed?

Tags: jquery

I am setting a data attribute from a `span` which contains a URL in a variable after a click on an item, then I am replacing the `span element` with an `iframe` with vimeo link provided by the variable. The code does a few of other things too:

HTML

```
<div class="item">
   <span class="video" data-vimeoid="http://vimeo.com/XXX"></span>
</div>
<div class="item">
   <span class="video" data-vimeoid="http://vimeo.com/YYY"></span>
</div>
<div class="item">
   <span class="video" data-vimeoid="http://vimeo.com/ZZZ"></span>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.item:not(.is-expanded)', function() {
  $(".item").removeClass('is-expanded');
  $(".caption").css("display", "block");
  $(".wrapVideo").css("display", "none");
  $("img").fadeIn();
  $(this).addClass('is-expanded');
  $(".is-expanded .caption").removeClass("loaded-caption").css("display", "none");
  $(".is-expanded img").css("display", "none");
  $(".is-expanded .wrapVideo").css("display", "block");
  $("#list").isotope("layout");
  var url = $('.is-expanded .video').data("vimeoid");
  var tokens = url.split("/");
  var id = tokens[3];
  var videoSpan =  $(".is-expanded").find("span.video");
  var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
    'frameborder' : 0,
    'class' : 'embed-responsive-item',
     'src' : 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ id + '?api=1&player_id=player webkitAllowFullScreen  mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen'
  });
  videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);
});
```

That works fine, but if an element has been clicked and the iframe has already replaced the span, then it shouldn't run the replacing code again, matter of fact the console is giving `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` as obviously it is running again that code but there is not more span element in the clicked item.

How to avoid running the code again to stop having that error in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.item:not(.is-expanded)', function() {
    $(".item").removeClass('is-expanded');
    $(this).addClass('is-expanded');
    $(".caption").css("display", "block");
    $(".item:not(.is-expanded) img").fadeIn();
    $(".item:not(.is-expanded) .wrapVideo").css("display", "none");
    var videoSpan =  $(this).find("span.video");
    var url = videoSpan.data("vimeoid");
    if(url){
        var tokens = url.split("/");
        var id = tokens[3];
        var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
                'frameborder' : 0,
                'class' : 'embed-responsive-item',
                'src' : 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ id + '?api=1&player_id=player webkitAllowFullScreen  mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen'
        });
        videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);
    } 
    $(".is-expanded .caption").removeClass("loaded-caption").css("display", "none");
    $(".is-expanded img").css("display", "none");
    $(".is-expanded .wrapVideo").css("display", "block");
    $("#list").isotope("layout");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your exact problem is but you can always just wrap the rest with an if

```
var url = $('.is-expanded .video').data("vimeoid");
if(url){
var tokens = url.split("/");
var id = tokens[3];
var videoSpan =  $(".is-expanded").find("span.video");
var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
  'frameborder' : 0,
  'class' : 'embed-responsive-item',
  'src' : 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ id + '?api=1&player_id=player webkitAllowFullScreen  mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen'
});
videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that var url = $('.is-expanded .video').data("vimeoid"); doesn't exist anymore once I execute it, so it is a waste of running code as well as the console obviously won't find URL

Comment: anyway I tried the if before, but even your code breaks with no error tho, the code. For some reasons that I don't get it, the img it is brought back to display block $(".is-expanded img").css("display", "none");

Comment: There is an error here `$('.is-expanded .video').data("vimeoid");` This will get the First .is-expanded .video if there are multiples it still returns the first

Comment: you need to use `$(this).find()` so you can be relative to the click

Comment: there is not error I can see, the actual code is working fine, all i want to do is to avoid running it again if it has already run and the span is replaced. I don't understand why it breaks if I insert an if as you did

Comment: ok i did use $(this).find even tho it wasn't really needed as .is-expanded can only be $this. The lines still breaks when i use the if as you suggested

Comment: my above code in the question works, the only thing is that it gievs that error in console and it runs each time even tho it has already run

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning the event to the actual class:

`<div class="item not-expanded">...</div>`

and in your javascript

```
$("item.not-expanded").on('click',function(){
   $(this).removeClass('not-expanded');
  //insert video
});
```

Comment: that is what I am doing with $(document).on( 'click', '.item:not(.is-expanded)', function() {

Comment: Not exactly... item:not(.is-expanded) will select the item that don't hae the class is-expanded. .item by itself qualify as such. where as the function written above will only select item with the not-expanded class together.
Try it!

Comment: but hang on, if I remove the class not-expanded, then i won't be able to ever click again on that item

Comment: you can add another function to handle the other events. use this one only to embed the video...

Comment: i still think this is doubling the coding without any additional value, I want to click on an item that it isn't expanded and if it is expanded i won't be able to click. by the time I click on a non expanded item I am removing the expanded class from any other items then adding the is expanded class. Anyway I am looking to know how to avoid running the other lines as described